# change site template by user in blog -ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, content-management-system

I want to create a simple CMS. Im wondering have to let user change website template.

similar to **wordpress** or **joomla** or **blogger**.

for example when use uses tag '', it replace whith site title.

in ASP.net C#.

thanks in advance.

Comment: why not use existing open source CMS for ASP.NET like [Orchard](http://orchardproject.net/)?

Comment: I DONT WANT to use an existing open source CMS.

Comment: When you pointed out Similar to wordpress, joomla or blogger. That when I thought you probably need a well proven solution. Are u willing to spend as much time as those three example to came out with similar product?

Comment: I dont want to create a cms as perfect as those 3. I just want to know what did they do for changing template.

Comment: The best is to install some of them, play with them, and see what they have do and how they do it.

Comment: I did that. but i didnt get it!